# Is it good to implement OAuth in JS and exposing Consumer Secret and Key?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, twitter-oauth

I want to develope a Twitter client for Chrome. I have seen JS files of existing twitter extensions for Chrome. And found their consumer key and secrets are exposed. I believe It's not the way that it should be.

I want to share my **opinion** that is server side. That user need to signup on my website. Have oAuth on that web. I will save their access tokens. And when they install my Chrome extension. I will ask them to login. And every time when they will tweet, I will fetch their access tokens online and made their tweet possible.

In this way, my keys will remain hidden. I don't want to use [Chrome OAuth](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_oauth.html).

Do you think my server side implementation of OAuth is better than JS implementaion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not sharing this data is in general a better idea, however it is harder to do in a Chrome Extension since it is more Front-End Development (unless you want to maintain your own server for the extension...).  I don't think there is too much risk in exposing your OAuth credentials.  If they are used maliciously to attack Twitter, Twitter will block the access and you can just apply for new keys.  Your users keys will be safely stored on their own machine so users data will be okay.  If you are looking for a easy way to implement the OAuth2 protocol in an extension, here is a utility I created just for that.

https://github.com/jjNford/oauth2-chrome-extension

I use this implementation my self in [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jgekomkdphbcbfpnfjgcmjnnhfikinmn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

Comment: Having bad luck with Chrome OAuth lib turn me to think server side solution. I will give a try to your lib, if I got successful to use it with Twitter.

Comment: @TahirAkram Cool, you may have to add a little to it to adapt it to twitters API but in general it should work.  I use it in the extension GitHub Repositories, which is hosted on my GitHub account also if you want to see how I am doing it.  If you get it working for twitter feel free to create a new branch in the OAuth repo.

Comment: The server side sounds gross... because if you quit maintaining it... your extension dies...

Comment: For server side there are some benefits too. And I will consider Google App Engine for that.